# RatingBar values duplicated in ExpandableListView

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview, android-adapter, ratingbar

When I rate something in First ExpandableListView:

[image: Rating Bar Pic 1]

Then when I open Second ExpandableListView or any other, the values are duplicated:

[image: Rating bar Pic 2]

I've taken help from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jZxZIFnJ9jE&ab_channel=EDMTDev
and just modified it by adding rating bar.
The ratings are not saved in the view.

**Code:**

**Java**

```
expListview = (ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.expSkills);
    initData();
    expListadapter = new ExpandablelistAdapter(getApplicationContext(),listDataheader,listHash);
    expListview.setAdapter(expListadapter);

  private void initData()
  {
    listDataheader = new ArrayList<>();
    listHash = new HashMap<>();

    listDataheader.add("Communication Skills");
    listDataheader.add("Social Skills");
    listDataheader.add("Music and Movement");
    listDataheader.add("Gross Motor Skills");
    listDataheader.add("Fine Motor Skills");
    listDataheader.add("Healthy Habits");

    List<String> a = new ArrayList<>();
    a.add("Follows Instructions :");
    a.add("Expresses in Words :");
    a.add("Asks Questions :");
    a.add("Answers Questions :");
    a.add("Uses Facial Expressions :");
    a.add("Listens and Enjoys :");

    List<String> b = new ArrayList<>();
    b.add("Shows Feelings and Emotions :");
    b.add("Participates in Group Activities :");
    b.add("Shares with Others :");
    b.add("Plays with Teacher :");
    b.add("Plays with all Friends :");
    b.add("Plays with only one or two Friends :");

    List<String> d = new ArrayList<>();
    d.add("Enjoys Physical Activities :");
    d.add("Enjoys EPL Activities :");
    d.add("Enjoys Playing :");
    d.add("Can Throw a Ball :");
    d.add("Can Catch a Ball :");
    d.add("Can Run,Jump :");
    d.add("Can Climb Equipment :");
    d.add("Can Balance on a Beam :");

    List<String> c = new ArrayList<>();
    c.add("Enjoys Listening Rhymes :");
    c.add("Enjoys Singing RRhymes :");
    c.add("Enjoys Performing Actions :");
    c.add("Enjoys Dancing :");
    c.add("Enjoys Attention of Others :");

    List<String> e = new ArrayList<>();
    e.add("Can String Beads :");
    e.add("Can Colour With Crayons :");
    e.add("Can Paint with Brush :");
    e.add("Can Put Together a Piece of Puzzle :");
    e.add("Can Stack a Net Of Blocks :");

    List<String> f = new ArrayList<>();
    f.add("Greets Everybody :");
    f.add("Eats Healthy Foode :");
    f.add("Drinks Water :");
    f.add("Eats Independently :");
    f.add("Happy to Come to School :");
    f.add("Plays Safely :");

    listHash.put(listDataheader.get(0),a);
    listHash.put(listDataheader.get(1),b);
    listHash.put(listDataheader.get(2),c);
    listHash.put(listDataheader.get(3),d);
    listHash.put(listDataheader.get(4),e);
    listHash.put(listDataheader.get(5),f);

}
```

**Adapter**

```
public class ExpandablelistAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter
{
private Context context;
private List<String> listDataheader;
private HashMap<String,List<String>> listHashMap;

public ExpandablelistAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataheader, HashMap<String, List<String>> listHashMap)
{
    this.context = context;
    this.listDataheader = listDataheader;
    this.listHashMap = listHashMap;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int i, int i1)
{return (listHashMap.get(listDataheader.get(i)).get(i1));} // i = Group Item , i1 = ChildItem

@Override
public long getChildId(int i, int i1) {
    return i1;
}

@Override // i - group position , i1 - child position b - isLastchild
public View getChildView(final int i, final int i1, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup)
{
    final String childText = (String)getChild(i,i1);
    ViewHolder holder;

    if(view==null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.expandable_list_items, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder(view);
        view.setTag(holder);
    }

    holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
    holder.features.setText(childText);
    holder.ratingbar.setTag(i1);

    holder.ratingbar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float v, boolean b)
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Rating : " + ratingBar.getRating() + " Skills : "+ i +" Position : " + i1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    return view;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int i) { return listHashMap.get(listDataheader.get(i)).size(); }


@Override
public Object getGroup(int i) {
    return listDataheader.get(i);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return listDataheader.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override // i - group position b - isExpanded
public View getGroupView(int i, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup)
{
    String headerTitle = (String)getGroup(i);
    if(view == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.expandable_list_group,null);
    }
    TextView listHeader = view.findViewById(R.id.expListHeader);
    listHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
    listHeader.setText(headerTitle);
    return view;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int i, int i1) {
    return true;
}

private static class ViewHolder
{
    RatingBar ratingbar;
    TextView features;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        ratingbar = view.findViewById(R.id.rate_img);
        features = view.findViewById(R.id.expListItem);
    }
}
}
```

I've wasted a lot of time on this..Where am I going wrong?

Comment: hi, you need to set rating number for `ratingbar` on `getChildView`, cause listview will re-use view => it will keep previous state that why you must set `ratingbar` again

Comment: yes, the updated answer is correctly executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using an holder :- Always remember to set it's tag when view is new/null and get it's tag when it's not. @azizbekian logic is to store and retrieve rating values which also worked.

**Code**

```
  @Override // i - group position , i1 - child position b - isLastchild
  public View getChildView(final int i, final int i1, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup)
  {
    final String childText = (String)getChild(i,i1);
    ViewHolder holder;

    if(view==null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.expandable_list_items, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder(view);
        view.setTag(holder);
    }

    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
    }

    holder.ratingbar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(onRatingChangedListener(holder, i, i1));

    holder.features.setText(childText);
    holder.ratingbar.setTag(i1);
    holder.ratingbar.setRating(arr[i][i1]);

    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ListView` recycles your views and reuses them. Once you check your `RatingBar` and scroll down, the exact same view is being reused. You have already checked the rating bar and haven't instructed to reset it, thus you see the same view with checked `RatingBar`.

To fix the issue you have to retain checked rating bar values in some kind of data structure, say in an array:

```
    int[][] arr = new int[groupCount][childCount];

    public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup)
    {
        ...
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        holder.ratingBar.setRating(arr[groupPosition][childPosition]);
        ...

        holder.ratingbar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float v, boolean b) {
                arr[groupPosition][childPosition] = (int) ratingBar.getRating();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
```

Comment: I understood what you're saying and I'm trying to implement that but the above code didn't work.

Comment: This is a sketch code, just to give you a way to follow further.

Comment: In this adapter getChildView() is getting called twice..can you see why? If not for this I can solve the problem

Comment: Why are you dependent on the quantity of calls of that function? You are on the wrong way, do not make assumptions on that.

Comment: On debug mode. The first call on view is correctly setting and getting rating values. Then it calls the view again and changes the values. That's what's happening.